# GitHub pull after changing project description?

Tags: github, pull

When I edit the project description on GitHub, do I have to pull the changes to my local repository? Or is the project description totally independent of the actual git repository data / commit data?
I changed the description and tried to git pull, but it says the local branch is up to date. Same when trying to commit a test commit without changing any file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the project description on github makes no change in your actual projects source tree, basically it means it registers no change or commits. Hence you will not require a pull in your local workspace.